# Running outside wiring for RV plug

Tags: electrical, wiring

Can I enclose the wiring inside PVC that is for electric?

It will run on the outside of a garage. I am running 50 amp 120 volt wiring for my RV hookup from the breaker box to the end of the garage on the outside with the proper size wire (8 gauge) 22ft.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use PVC conduit? It's done all the time. What specific question do you have? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: How did you arrive at 8 gauge as the wire size for 50A?

Comment: You need at least 6 Ga copper or 4 Ga aluminum for NEC ampacity sizing. Hint - the aluminum is a LOT cheaper. And your standard 50A RV plug is 120/240, not 120 volt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PVC is made for this purpose. If it is an area exposed to vehicular traffic and could be struck by a car you should consider schedule 80 PVC.

Otherwise, schedule 40 is the standard for outdoor electrical.

A 50 amp RV plug should probably be 240 volts though.

Good luck and stay safe!